# How to fix the background image adjust to div?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following div for calendar and I need to adjust the background image and text accordingly. How do I do that?

[image]

My code:

```css
.calenderArrivalDiv{
 margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
 background-image: url("images/SearchReservation/search_button_u754.png");
    text-align: center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 12%;
    text-align: center;
}

.calenderDepDiv{
 margin-top: 14%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
 background-image: url("images/SearchReservation/search_button_u754.png");
    text-align: center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
      <div id="arrivalDate" class="calenderArrivalDiv calanderSize" 
       ng-click="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpen($event)">
        <span>
         <button tabindex="4" class="dateSearchBar" class="btn btn-primary" id="one"
          datepicker-popup="{{'MMM d'}}"
          ng-model="searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate"
          is-open="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpened"
          ng-change="searchReservationVm.arrivalDateChange()"
          datepicker-options="dateOptions"
          show-weeks="false"
          current-text="Reset To Today's Date"
          ng-focus="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpen($event)">
          <div class="text calFontDate" title="Select Arrival Date">
           {{ searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'MMM' }}</br>
           <div class="datediv">
           {{  searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'd' }}
           </div>
          </div>
         </button>
        </span>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this..its not clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add `background-size:cover` where you added background image it will shift inside of `DIV`

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what exactly the background here, are you talking about the blue square ?

Anyways Seems that your div size is small, or you don't have the width / height set.

Comment: yes background is blue square. If i try to set height and width (in %), its not applying.